# Diferencia entre System.err y System.out

Tags: java

He estado investigando un poco y encuentro que son esencialmente lo mismo.

Estoy aprendiendo java y en un ejercicio de sacar el área de un rectángulo cometí el error de colocar `System.err` en lugar de `.out` del ejemplo en el que estaba estudiando.

Con el `.err` se detenía sin mostrar error en Netbeans pero todo salió correctamente con el `.out`, ¿o sea que no son iguales?

```
package area;

public class Rectangulo {
    private int base;
    private int altura;
    private int area;
    
    public Rectangulo(int base , int altura){
        this.base = base;
        this.altura = altura;
        
    }
    
    public void CalculoArea (){
        area = base * altura;
    }
    
    public void Imprimir(){
        CalculoArea();
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + area);// <---aqui tenia .err
    }
    
}
```

Me gustaría tener bien entendida esta parte antes de seguir avanzando :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los procesos que corren en una computadora tienen dos salidas por lo general: La salida estándar y la salida de error.

La salida estándar es en donde generalmente se imprimen mensajes visibles al usuario y la salida de error es donde se imprimen mensajes de error, cuando algo sale mal o pasa algo inesperado, dicho lo anterior se debe de usar el System.error por ejemplo al cachar una exception es decir en:

```
try{
   int a= 10, b=2;
   int c = a/b;
   System.out.println("Mensaje de resultado = "+ c);  
}catch(Exception e){
   System.err.println("Mensaje de Error  "+e);
}
```

Comment: Es correcto. No debería usarse nunca `System.err` fuera de un contexto de error.

Answer (score 1):

`System.err` es similar a `System.out`. La diferencia es que `System.err` normalmente se usa para generar textos de error. Incluso algunos editores, como por ejemplo Eclipse, muestran estos mensajes en color rojo, para que sea mas obvio que es un error. Pero hacen las misma función, imprimir en consola.

Comment: Realmente no son lo mismo. Haz esta prueba poniendo estas dos líneas en este orden: `System.out.println("Out"); System.err.println("Error");` En la consola, verás que **el mensaje `Error` se imprime antes que `Out`, a pesar de estar después en el código**. Esto es porque `System.err` imprime en otro flujo que es `stderr`, el cual tiene prioridad, mientras que `System.out`  trabaja con `stdout`. No son para nada similares.